# Sending data through activity and fragments issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have one activity and two fragments.

The activity loads FirstFragment and FirstFragment Loads SecondFragment.

I want to pass a string value from The activity to the SecondFragment.

What i did is :

```
   //I was getting the string from the adapter
  Intent i = getIntent();
  String id_livestream = i.getStringExtra("id_livestream");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),id_livestream,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//i am getting here 22
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id_livestream", id_livestream);
            FirstFragment firstfragment = new FirstFragment();
            firstfragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

On FirstFragment class on CreateView:

```
if (bundle != null) {
        String strtext=getArguments().getString("id_livestream");
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),strtext,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

I was just trying to send it to the firstFragment to see if it will works but i am getting **null**
I tried using this.getArugments() and adding the code to onActivityCreated() and nothing worked i am still getting null value.

Comment: It may possible that id_livestream is null.try with random string.

Comment: No it s not null ..i toasted the message before sending it to the fragment and i get : 22

Comment: add .tostring() in toast. Toast.makeText(getContext(),strtext.tostring(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

Using Serialization always works.:

In Activity:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("id_livestream", value);
aFragment.setArguments(args);
```

In Fragment:

```
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
String stringValue= (String) arguments.getSerializable("id_livestream");
```

Comment: Same result i am getting null

Answer (score 0):

In activity start first fragment

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("id_livestream", id_livestream);
    firstfragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, firstFragment , "firstFragment ");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in FirstFragment in onViewCreated method

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    String id_livestream = this.getArguments().getString("id_livestream");
 }
```

then call SecondFragment and put bundle on the same way as for the first fragment

```
    SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("id_livestream", id_livestream); // or this.getArguments().getString("id_livestream")
    secondFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, secondFragment, "secondFragment");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in `Activity`

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    FirstFragment myFrag = new FirstFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fname",Android);
    myFrag.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.bcontainer, myFrag , "firstFragment ");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Code in `Fragment`

```
    sname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.showname);
    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    String myStr = bundle.getString("fname");
    sname.setText("Name:"+myStr);
```

This works perfectly.Happy coding.